# How to get a day of the week variable - Swift 2, Xcode, ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I am new to code. I just want someone to tell me how I can get a day of the week variable in my code and where should I put it. Do I put it in ViewController.swift, AppDelegate.swift, where?

I then want to program a button to go to a certain View Controller using performSeguewithIdentifier. I have made the identifiers 1Mon, 1Tue, 1Wed, 1Thu and 1Fri, each going from a certain view controller to another.

When you provide the day of the week variable code, I need to know where to put it in because it is driving me round the bend. When I get the code, how do I implement it to a button. I have attempted to do this.

```
@IBAction func Wk1(sender: AnyObject) {
            if var weekDay == "Monday" {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("1Mon", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

I have no idea where to put the code to make the variable weekDay so that is one possible reason why this code is failing. I also do not know how to format the if command while including a variable. I've tried putting the code I have been given and found in AppDelegate.swift, and in ViewController.swift I tried putting it under `@IBAction func Wk1(sender: AnyObject) {` and under `import UIKit`. All 3 didn't work. I have tried using the following code.

```
func getDayOfWeek(today:String)->Int? {
    let formatter  = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if let todayDate = formatter.dateFromString(today) {
        let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let myComponents = myCalendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: todayDate)
        let weekDay = myComponents.weekday
        return weekDay
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have a button action somewhere. So the dayOfWeek code should go in that button action. On the click of that button you would decide which segueIdentifier to call, and then call it.

Comment: Directly under the `@IBAction`? And I get errors when implementing the code. Can you tell if it's Swift 2 ready or not?

Comment: Yes. Also, are you getting the date string from somewhere? or you're making decision on the current date?

Comment: I don't know to be honest! Should use date from the phone.

Comment: Do you not understand my question? Or you're not sure about the requirement at hand?

Comment: Should just use the current date on the handset. Not from internet source etc.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to format getting an if command from variable and could you demo the code using one of my segues listed in question? @iosDev82

Comment: Updated the answer. Change your segueIdentifiers to weekDay names so that you don't have to use god awful variables like '1Mon'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your code like this.

```
@IBAction func Wk1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var date = NSDate()
    let formatter  = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    var weekDayString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    performSegueWithIdentifier(weekDayString, sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Where do I specify the day and my segue identifiers eg. 1Mon, 1Tue and so on

Comment: @DylanA Change your segue identifiers to full names like Monday, Tuesday. 
Also, upvote and accept the answer if you've found it helpful.

Comment: Could you add an example of how I'd implement it with an Identifier. I want to create this again within the same app for another week - it's a school planner app you see and my school runs on a fortnight timetable system.

Comment: @DylanA I don't understand what you mean by a different identifier. For each different day, it will return a different day of the week, and a different segueIdentifier will be called.

Comment: If I implement this code all over again with another set of segues 2Monday, 2Tuesday, where can I just wham in the 2.

Comment: concatenate in front of the weekDayString.

Comment: So it makes `performSegueWithIdentifier(2weekDayString, sender: nil) }`? And do I need to put any code prior to this anywhere?

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier("2" + weekDayString, sender: nil)`

Comment: Where would I put the 2 in that bit of code is my question

Comment: I have 2 weeks with each day having a timetable. 10 view controllers each having each day's timetable in. I know for the first week it's a matter of doing Monday, Tuesday etc as segue names. For the second week, to avoid conflict, I'll stick a 2 on the front, where do I put that 2 in that string of code you pointed out.